# Should epub and epub3 tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I've answered to a question today and noticed that we have a specific [epub3](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epub3) tag, in addition to the more generic [epub](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epub).

Should we merge those?

I think that the different version of the specification could be easily addressed in the question text. After all, we don't have a tag for epub 2, and if in the future other versions will come out, we will need even more tags for essentially the same thing.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since nobody is weighing in and I agree that these two tags should be merged, I just went ahead and did it (epub3 -> epub... with a new tag synonym). If there is anything that is epub version specific, we can always change the tags to be separate again and retag questions that warrant it.